# Generating random lat/long coordinates

Tags: r, coordinates, united-kingdom, random, leaflet-r

Dedicated [**page on use of leaflet in R**](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html) provides a very useful example on generating random latitude and longitude values for Central Europe:

```
cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)
```

which results in neatly distributed points:

[image: picture from leaflet page]

*(Source: [Leaflet official page](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html))*

I'm interested in generating a similar set of randomly generated points by, broadly, ***corresponding to the UK***. For instance, how can I use the latitude and longitude map available through [*Maps of World*](http://www.mapsofworld.com/lat_long/united-kingdom-lat-long.html) to arrive at the `X`, `Y` and `Z` values in the formula below so the generated dots would, roughly, fell across the British Isles?

```
cbind(rnorm(40) * X + Y, rnorm(40) + Z)
```

[image: Lat/Long Map]

---

I'm interested in a rough approximation, if some points will fall in the see or outside the UK that's fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is to generate a random set of numbers within the following approximated box:

```
[Longitude,      Latitude]
[-10.8544921875, 49.82380908513249],
[-10.8544921875, 59.478568831926395],
[2.021484375,    59.478568831926395],
[2.021484375,    49.82380908513249]
```

Source for these points is https://gist.github.com/UsabilityEtc/6d2059bd4f0181a98d76 , but it could just as well be taken from Google Earth or similar.

The method for choosing random points that you suggest relies calculations and offsets. I suggest a different approach called `runif`.

Instead of using:

```
cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)
```

You could be using:

```
cbind(runif(40,-10.8544921875,2.021484375),runif(40,49.82380908513249,59.478568831926395))
```

Main difference that you'll see is more scattered data, which is caused by the fact that `ruinf` creates randomly distributed data, while `rnorm` creates normally distributed data.

If you want normally distributed data, instead of using the scaling and offset tricks that the leaflet example uses, you could simply scale the output from `rnorm` between the values indicated in my formula.

Comment: The problem is that the points will not actually be uniformly distributed, due to the gross distortions in the Plate Carree projection you have implicitly adopted--especially in northerly regions like England.  For a truly uniform distribution, project the data using an equal area projection, generate the points, then (if needed) unproject them.  There is an excellent approximation that avoids the project-unproject cycle: generate uniform longitudes and uniform *cosines* of the latitudes and apply the inverse cosine to those. (This is an equal-area cylindrical projection of the sphere.)